# UIScroll in a UIView doing strange things

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have two UIScrollViews in a UIView on the IB.

[image]

Each one of the UIScrollViews have buttons which go horizontally. 
The height of the buttons on the top UIScrollView are 70
the height of the button on the bottom UIScrollView are say 60 
Then there is some padding added which is 10px

So I set the UIScrollViews to that and on one the buttons are half on the view and on the other they are on in the UIScrollView but without any padding.

[image]

Any advice on adding UIScrollViews to UIView so they sit correctly and don't do any vertical scrolling (only horizontal) and the buttons fit snug in the UIScrollView.

This is the code to set up the UIScrollViews.

```
let scrollingView = ScrollViewEventType(CGSizeMake(62.0,62.0), buttonCount: 10)
        EventScroll.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
        EventScroll.addSubview(scrollingView)
        EventScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        EventScroll.indicatorStyle = .Default


        let datescrollingview = ScrollViewDateType(CGSizeMake(124.0, 70.0), buttonCount: 6)
        DateScroll.contentSize = datescrollingview.frame.size
        DateScroll.addSubview(datescrollingview)
        DateScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        DateScroll.indicatorStyle = .Default
```

This is for the two UIScrollViews

```
func ScrollViewEventType(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {
        //creates color buttons in a UIView
        let padding = CGSizeMake(10, 10)
        let buttonView = UIView()
        DateScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.84, green: 0.90, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        DateScroll.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 2)
        buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
        buttonView.frame.size.height = (buttonSize.height +  padding.height)

        //add buttons to the view
        var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(padding.width * 0.5, padding.height)
        let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width


        for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
            var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
            button.frame.size = buttonSize
            button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.13, green: 0.48, blue: 0.81, alpha: 1.0)
            button.tag = i
            button.addTarget(self, action: "EventButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
        }
        return buttonView
    }
```

Comment: Why did you post the same code twice?

Comment: let me ammend thanks